# How to implement multiple search filters API's at once in django-rest framework?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework

I am  working on advance search feature and the apis for the search feature are

1. set of words to search
2. exact word or phrase
3. any of the words
4. none of these words

I have to  filter the queryset using these API's  and use all the API's at once and i have developed a single search field API by referring the link

Django rest-framework filters

Code for the search field

```
 class JournalListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Journal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JournalSerializer
    pagination_class = JournalPagination
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('title','abstract')
    search_fields = ('@title', '@abstract')
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using django-filter (https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter).

Create a filterset for your model.
Then you can filter data using such a query as

```
API_URL/?field__exact=value
```

Related documentation for DRF: 
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html